# Need help creating a directive that performs TypeAhead functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

### Background

If any of you are familiar with the Evernote desktop application, when adding tags to a note, you are able to start typing the name of the tag. Once you begin typing, "help text" appears to assist you in selecting the right tag. So it functions as a filter.  I need a control that functions just like this for my web application.

### What I Have So Far

In my `controllers.js` file, I have defined the following property for temporary testing.  This property will be populated with data from an API once I get this working with test data.

`$scope.data.types = {Types: [{name: 'Developer'}, {name: "\"Developer Company\""}, {name: 'Accountant'}, {name: "\"Legal Counsel\""}]};`

In my route template file `contacts-edit.html`, I have the following piece of relevant code.  Basically, I have an editable `<div>` that pulls in and displays persistent tags (i.e. tags that have been saved for this contact in the database) from `$scope.data.contacts`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="entity_types" class="control-label col-sm-2">Tags</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-control" contenteditable="true" ng-model="data.contact.EntityTypes" my-Directive my-Other-Directive></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my `directives.js` file resides code for `myDirective` and `myOtherDirective`.  The `myDirective` directive uses the `ngModel` to provide 2-way data binding. Thus, when a user types in the `div`, on `blur` the tags are added to the model and formatted to look similar to a tag. These tags are space delimited and will allow for spaces for tags between double quotes to be ignored.  So `myDirective` functions the way I want it to.

However, I'm a little stumped on how to provide the filter functionality which I'll look to provide through the `myOtherDirective` directive.  I'm probably going about this all wrong so any help would be beneficial.

### The `myOtherDirective` Directive

So the idea here is that as soon as the end user starts typing, a `<span>` displays directly beneath the `<div>` that displays filtered results that is using data from `scope.data.types.Types` as the model data to filter against.  The results do not need to be clickable or anything, they are merely there to assist the end user in entering the correct tag for the contact.

**Code**

```
directives.directive('myOtherDirective', [function() {

    var template = "<span class='help-block'>" +
        "<ul class='list-unstyled list-inline'>" +
        "<li ng-repeat='type in data.types.Types'><small>{{type.name}}</small></li>" +
        "</ul></span>";

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('focus', function(e) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                element.parent().append(template);
            });
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            type: '='
        },
        template: template
    };
}]);
```

So, I was able to get the help block to display as soon as the `<div>` gains focus (it's removed on `blur` by the way).  I couldn't get the data binding to work on `data.types.Types` and was at a loss for where to go next.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get autocomplete working for an input box I would use [ui-bootstrap's typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I took a look at the TypeAhead functionality and this is very close to what I am looking for.  However, when you enter multiple words/tags in the text box, the type ahead won't work. Also, it probably won't work if there are currently values in the textbox/div.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the `type` parameter into your directive it causes it to have an isolated scope. This means that you won't be able to access `$scope.data` form inside your directive. To fix this you could pass `data` in as well.

```
scope: {
    type: '='
    data: '='
}
```